# Showing a random variable has a finite expectation

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

The generalized inverse Gaussian distribution GIG(a,b,p) has pdf

$$f(x) = \dfrac{(a/b)^{p/2}}{2K_p(\sqrt{ab})}x^{p-1}e^{-(ax+b/x)/2}$$

for x > 0 and f(x) = 0 otherwise. Parameters a and b are positive and $p \in (-\infty, \infty)$. The modified Bessel function $K_p$ is apart of the normalizing constant but knowledge of it is not needed.

Does X have a finite expectation? What conditions on (a,b,p) do you need to impose
in order for X to have a finite expectation?

Based off this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution, it does appear that the expectation is finite. However, I'm wondering how do I show this. I'm struggling to solve the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)dx$$

which is my first approach. Are there any other ways to show that X has a finite expectation?

Comment: @geetha290krm As far as I can tell it has a finite mean $\forall p$.

Comment: @geetha290krm See my answer.

Comment: Just check that $\,\displaystyle \dfrac{(a/b)^{p/2}}{2K_p(\sqrt{ab})}\int_0^\infty x^{p-1}e^{-(ax+b/x)/2}dx=1\,$ first, and you understand the pattern. For example, 
$$\int_0^\infty x^{p-1}e^{-(ax+b/x)/2}dx=\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,\,\Big)^p \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^{p-1}e^{-\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{2}(t+1/t)}dt$$
Using $x=e^t$
$$=\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,\,\Big)^p \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{px}e^{-\sqrt{ab}\cosh x}dx=2\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,\,\Big)^p \int_0^\infty \cosh(px)e^{-\sqrt{ab}\cosh x}dx=2\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,\,\Big)^pK_p(\sqrt{ab})$$ formula 10.32.9 https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring prefactors, you end up with
$$\int_0^\infty x^p\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right)\right)\mathrm dx$$
Introduce $t=ax/2$ to reduce the number of parameters from three to two:
$$=(2/a)^{p+1}\int_{0}^\infty t^p\exp\left(-t-\frac{z^2}{4t}\right)\mathrm dt$$
With $z=\sqrt{ab}$. Finally let $p=-\nu-1$:
$$=(2/a)^{-\nu}\int_0^\infty t^{-\nu-1}\exp\left(-t-\frac{z^2}{4t}\right)\mathrm dt$$
This integral is [well known](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32),
$$\int_0^\infty t^{-\nu-1}\exp\left(-t-\frac{z^2}{4t}\right)\mathrm dt=2(z/2)^{-\nu}K_\nu(z)$$
It converges for all $\nu\in\mathbb C$ provided $\operatorname{arg}z<\pi/4$.